# Sending transactions to smart contract every 3 seconds

Tags: transactions, web3.py, python, pancakeswap

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while now and would really appreciate any help i can get.

i am essentially trying to create a loop that doesnt stop after one succesful tx. End goal is to produce a loop that will run the function which sends a tx to the smart contract.
I have the function all sorted and its a simple tx to a smart contract on pancakeswap router.

Ive now tried a While True: loop, as well as the Scheduler but can never get it to run the function more than once, as once the statement is 'True' it simply stops.
I just want to send tx every 3 seconds to a smart contract its that simple ahha!!

I would really appreciate any guidance

Thank you!

Example Code:

```
Pancakeswaptx = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
    0,
    [spend,tokentobuy],
    my_address,
    (int(start)+ 10000)
    ).buildTransaction({
    'from': my_address,
    'value': web3.toWei(0.001,'ether'),
    'gas': 250000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5','gwei'), 
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_address),
    })

def runtx():
    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(Pancakeswaptx, privatekey)
    transaction = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    print(web3.toHex(transaction))

while True: 
    time.sleep(1)
    runtx()
```

Note: i get the following error after 1 iteration and succesful tx, both when i use the loop and scheduler:

```
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'already known'}
```

Comment: show code (remove private infos) please, otherwise noone can help

Comment: @MajdTL, added some example code using the 'while True' loop

Comment: I think you are providing the exact same transaction everytime. The nonce part is especially problematic. Try incrementing the nonce for every transaction.

Comment: @Itération122442 surely the nonce would just update after each tx as its just counting the tx count? so when i run it again after a tx itll be one higher

Comment: Nonce goes up when the transaction is mined. I doubt it is mined in less than 1 second, as per your script.

Comment: ok interesting, makes sense. so either do nonce + 1 for each tx of just increase the time between each tx to allow for it to be mined? @Itération122442

Comment: Nonce + 1 or wait for the transaction to be mined. Time is not a good referential.

Answer (score 0):

if you think first tx sholud mine

```
def runtx():
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(Pancakeswaptx, privatekey)
transaction = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)    
wait_tx = web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(transaction)
if wait_tx:
    nonce = nonce + 1
```

if transaction mine is nor important

```
def runtx():
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(Pancakeswaptx, privatekey)
transaction = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(transaction))
nonce = nonce + 1
```